# Find folders in incorrect location via regex

Tags: regex

Question is about file management but I think it can be relatively easily solved with regex. I just don't know how to write expression I need

In my company, we have a huge number of projects. Data is stored on the network drive in folders and it looks like this:

```
Y:\1234_PROJECT THIS
Y:\1257_PROJECT THAT
etc.
```

Sometimes people accidentally drag whole project folders somewhere randomly into other project's folders and don't notice

I can get a list of all the folders on the server and would like to go through them using regex to find out if anything was dragged accidentally.

What I know is that in each project folder there is subfolder `XXXX_ADMIN\` where `XXXX` is four digit identifier.

what I would like is to find all of those which match the following (pseudo)pattern

```
Y:\XXXX_*\!XXXX_ADMIN\*
```

Basically, there shouldn't be ADMIN folder from incorrect project inside another one.

to clarify:

from those four examples I need to find 1, 2 and 3 but not 4 nor 5:

```
Y:\1234_CORRECT PROJECT LOCATION\1234_ADMIN\SUBFOLDER\5678_INCORRECT PROJECT LOCATION\5678_ADMIN\5678_SOMEFOLDER\5678_SUBFOLDER\
Y:\1234_CORRECT PROJECT LOCATION\SUBFOLDER\5678_INCORRECT PROJECT LOCATION\5678_ADMIN\5678_SOMEFOLDER\5678_SUBFOLDER\
Y:\1234_CORRECT PROJECT LOCATION\5678_INCORRECT PROJECT LOCATION\5678_ADMIN\5678_SOMEFOLDER\5678_SUBFOLDER\
Y:\1234_CORRECT PROJECT LOCATION\SUBFOLDER\1234_CORRECT\1234_NOTADMIN\1234_SOMEFOLDER\1234_SUBFOLDER\
Y:\1234_CORRECT PROJECT LOCATION\1234_ADMIN\1234_SOMEFOLDER\1234_SUBFOLDER\
```

Thank you for help!

I think I solved it. this expression seems to be working for me:

```
Y:\\([0-9]{4})_.*(?<!\1)_ADMIN\\.*
```

Comment: This should match the good ones - `Y:\\(\d+)?_.*?((\1)_ADMIN\\).*?` (you could also limit it to exactly 4 digits if needed). Now just look at the ones that don't match. Would that work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not. there are other subfolders inside the main folder which are not necessarily _ADMIN. Like Y:\1234_PROJECT\1234_IN\... _ADMIN is the only one I am certain of that's why I would like to look for it.

Comment: What flavor of regex?

Comment: I am not that familiar with flavours. I am working in regexbuddy so I can test the general idea. If I find something that is working I will export it to the appropriate language and run from there on the text file?

Comment: Quoting from the regex tag: *Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.*  The regex for this may require a Perl compatible regex. Knowing that you have access to the correct tool is important. Perl regex is not at all similar to a sed regex for example. What language or tool is available to you?

Comment: I would probably be most familiar with processing that further in either PHP or ruby. not sure what flavours those use

Answer (score 0):

Your expression:

```
Y:\\([0-9]{4})_.*(?<!\1)_ADMIN\\.*
```

does not seem to work: [test](https://regex101.com/r/JPnbtW/1)

This expression:

```
Y:\\([0-9a-zA-Z_ ]+\\){2,}(\d{4}_ADMIN)
```

catches exactly what you want: [test](https://regex101.com/r/405mXe/1/)